# Adding attribute to spotlight for a system type (UTI public.audio)

Tags: macos, spotlight, spotlight-plugin

I'd very want to add several more attributes (or columns in DB terms) to audio files on OSX. I've read the manual [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/Importers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001283-CJBEJBHH) but it states that: "Only one importer is allowed per uniform type identifiers (UTIs)." 
There is an identifier for public.audio UTI, so technically my importer cannot work.

However I suspect there should be a non straightforward way how to achieve this, probably via declaration one more UTI class or by chaining my importer before a system one. Any ideas appreciated.